# How to determine if current user has access to a specific folder?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have tried different approaches with no luck

```
var user = Session.getUser();
var userEmail = user.getEmail();
var viewers = someFolder.getViewers()
return (user in viewers)
```

Also this

```
return (userEmail in viewers)
return (viewers.indexOf(userEmail) != -1)
```

It might trivial, but not for me

Thanks, Fausto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Folder.getViewers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_folder#getViewers) method returns a list of users and your code searches an email which is a string in a list of users which are objects. A solution is

```
function testUser() {
  var bUserFound = false;
  var user = Session.getUser();
  var userEmail = user.getEmail();
  var viewers = someFolder.getViewers();
  for (var i = 0; i < viewers.length; i++) {
    var viewer = viewers[i];
    if (viewer.getEmail() == userEmail) {
      bUserFound = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return bUserFound;
}
```